# Enabling javascript intellisense for external libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellisense, visual-studio-2013

I updated `~/Scripts/_references.js` with

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-route.js" />
```

and in my `app.js` I can see some intellisense working, which is great

[image: angular.js intellisense working]

but go a little further and it doesn't work anymore.

[image: angular.js intellisense not working]

Any ideas on why this happens or ways to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are using `dependency injection`, Visual Studio has no way to figure out what are the types of the arguments.

This is a common problem with [Javascript intellisense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh395059.aspx) and, since Javascript does not allow for explicit type annotations, it seems that there is no clear way to work around it.

However, this can be achieved easily using [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) (which has a VS2013 extension) and [angular types](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs) where your code would look like:

```
angular.module('example', ['ngRoute'])
  .config([ '$locationProvider',
    function ($locationProvider : ng.ILocationProvider) {

           $locationProvider. // Intellisense would work here.
    }
   ]);
```

Comment: the DI factor makes sense. WebStorm manages to figure it out, was hoping VS could too. Not sure I want to add the DefinitelyTyped stuff to my code, I'll give it a shot though and see how it works. Thanks

Comment: @qntmfred Do note that those are merely type definitions and will not _really_ add anything to your code.No type annotations will remain in the final compiled code either.

Answer (score 7):

I built a library to do just this:

https://github.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot. I tried to figure out how you achieved this but they are lot of things I don't really understand. Would you have a tutorial you could advice to make such extension please?

Comment: I'd love to but don't have time for that I'm afraid. Explore the source, add logging, watch how it works. Hopefully you'll be able to pick up where I left off and continue to make improvements.

Comment: This project was folded into the Modern.Intellisense.js file in VS Web Essentials. I plan to make some significant updates soon.