# JavaScript namespace references in IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces

I'm learning how to put all my JS inside a namespace and how add other things to the same namespace. I'm using VS 2013 with a MVC page.

Here I create `skillet` in first `namespace.js` with some properties, then in `namespace2.js` add another property.

As you can see in HTML after adding both JS I can see all properties. 
But inside `namespace2.js` cant see properties from `namespace.js`

[image]

My idea is have a main JS for all my projects, and use the second one to fine details depending on specifics requirements.

**Is there a way second JS know what is define in first JS?**

Something like:

```
#include "namespace.js" 
using namespace.js;
<script>namespace.js</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `/// <reference ...>`  directive as you can see in [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb385682.aspx#Features)

Other useful answers in SO:

[Best Practices for IntelliSense JavaScript references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978224/best-practices-for-intellisense-javascript-references)

[Enabling javascript intellisense for external libraries in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569173/enabling-javascript-intellisense-for-external-libraries-in-visual-studio)